# "Paradise" vs. "heaven"

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference in use between "paradise" and "heaven"?

I feel that *heaven* is more spiritual, something that probably couldn't even be imagined. When you say *paradise*, you can denote something more real. Imagine a vacation on a tropical island; you can say, "I was in Bahamas. It was a paradise". But heaven is something even more unseizable.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "I was in Bahamas. It was a paradise" -- not *heaven*. Usage-wise, we call something *Paradise* when referring to how **it** is; whereas we speak of *heaven* when speaking about how **we** feel about it. "I spent a week in the Bahamas. Life was heaven!"

Comment: @Kris: "it was paradise" vs "it was heaven" in that narrow context they're pretty much the same.

Comment: "It was like *heaven* when Chase walked up and kissed me on my cheek that morning..." (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=X6Fn51cu3LcC&pg=PA61)
"A *paradise* called Texas" (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=WSvcPgAACAAJ)
 -- ...

Comment: "It was a *paradise* perfectly equipped for the survival of all of God's creatures ..." (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=VIMj6gP3Q9wC&pg=PA37)
"We learned that Fairfield, "quietest town in the U.S.," was close to Travis, so I and my classmates decided to go see it for ourselves. On the way there in the cab, we came upon a nightclub with nude dancers. We had to stop and go inside. It was like *heaven* for us young guys. I'd never seen anything like this in my life. We never made it to Fairfield." (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=tLvy_THW7EAC&pg=PA136)

Comment: "I'm reminded of my own kindergarten graduation years ago. Back before schools were plagued with problems like ADHD, peanut allergies, or minorities. Why, it was like *heaven*, no rapture required." (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=xmLAsxMemKgC&pg=PA148)

Comment: @Mitch It could not have been titled "A heaven called Texas" for obvious reasons.

Comment: Paradise is a king's garden; heaven is the abode of God.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the literal sense, paradise is a perfect earthly world, free of misery.  Heaven is where good people go when they die.

Either can be used in a metaphorical sense, and in fact, heaven probably has wider metaphorical use.  It fits in your example for a tropical island, but you could also use it to describe something you find very pleasant.  For example,

> That chocolate ice-cream is heaven!

Comment: I'm used to people saying "heavenly" rather than "heaven" in your ice-cream example.

Comment: People use both.  Alicia Keys for example says "Motherhood is heaven."  In the opinion of the Houston Chronicle "... the gingered Anarkali cocktail is heaven."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "in the literal sense...."

Comment: Thanks for response. OK, so this means that I was quite wrong, heaven is also used for earthly things... And what about *paradise*? Does it fit to the tropical island or the ice-cream?

Comment: @Tomas Yes your example is ok (although I would probably say something like "It's paradise on earth!"), and as I mentioned heaven also fits (minus the article): "I was in the Bahamas, it was heaven!"  Or use Monica's suggestion: "It was heavenly." which is weaker, more simile than metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Heaven (from the German for sky) is specifically christian. Paradise (from Persian garden) has less distinct religious overtones

Comment: Not specifically Christian according to this: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/heaven

Comment: While it's true that, for example, [heofon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven#Etymology) in Old English may have changed meaning due to Christianization, it would also be silly to say that the way we use *heaven* today is specifically Christian; we obviously use it both in figurative senses and to refer to a variety of religions when discussing them in English. I'm also not sure why you say that [paradise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=paradise) is less religious: it got much of its connotation because it referred to the Garden of Eden.

Comment: See http://www.infidelguy.com/heaven_sky.htm

Answer (score 0):

Paradise means a heavenly beautiful place on this Earth. But Heaven refers to a place beyond the atmospheric limitation where the God reside.

Answer (score 0):

For me , paradise is place that we can imagine but heaven is place that we can't predict where it is or how it looks.

Ex: I was in Paris,  it was a paradise full of good people.

Answer (score -2):

I think when Jesus said "Today you will be with me in Paradise", He meant heaven for He says to be absent from the body is to be present with The Lord.

He had to go back there to get what He shed for our sins, then He went to hell to take back the keys Adam forfeited and to take the sting out of death.

When we think of paradise it's about some place exotic for we think with our natural mind but Jesus was speaking of Spiritual things/places.

Comment: This does not answer the question for English at large; it is simply an interpretation of a bit of Christian theology.